# Mac os x writeToFile not working using xcode5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist, writetofile

I'm trying to modify a plist and saving the changes but it doesn't work:

here is my code:

```
        NSString *myPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSMutableDictionary *plistDict;
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[plistDict objectForKey:@"$objects"]];
        for (int i =0 ; i <array.count; i++)
        {
            if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"myString"])
                {
    [[plistDict objectForKey:@"$objects"]replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"newString"];

    }
    }
    }
     NSString *root = @"/Users/myUser/Desktop/newPlist.plist";
        [plistDict writeToFile:root atomically:YES];
```

the dictionary of the content is been modify and I don't have any errors but the file is never been created in the path. Any of you know what I'm doing wrong? or how can I fixed?

Comment: Check whether yor plistdict contains some data or not??

Comment: I po plistdict and is not empty

Comment: ok then, did you check whther your newplistfile path exist??

Comment: Use the version of the method that accepts an `NSError` object and find out what the problem is yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are writing to a Sandboxed location. Not actually to the users directory.

Comment: That directory is forbidden under sandboxing, but this is a wild guess as the OP hasn't mentioned sandboxing.

Comment: is a mac app. Can write to any location

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below code:-

```
NSMutableDictionary *plistDict=//assuming your data
        NSString *root = @"/Users/home/Desktop/newPlist.plist";
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:root])//checking fileexist or not 
    {
//if not exist creating the same 
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createFileAtPath:root contents:nil attributes:nil];
        [plistDict writeToFile:root atomically:YES];
    }
    else
    {
    [plistDict writeToFile:root atomically:YES];
    }
```